# Are the gods of water and sky ever explicitly equated?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, religion

In the world of Ice and Fire there are many religions whose gods are quite similar. In particular, here are some of the gods of water and sky/weather:

```
                    Water               Sky
The Ironborn        The Drowned God     The Storm God
The Three Sisters   Lady of the Waves   Lord of the Skies
The Rhoynar         Mother Rhoyne
The Storm Kings     The sea god         Goddess of the wind
```

One of the concepts in the books is that many of the gods are given different names by different peoples, such as [the Many-Faced God](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Many-Faced_God) who is called 'the Black Goat', 'the Lion of Night' and 'the Stranger'.

Do the books also explicitly equate any of these water and sky/weather gods?

Comment: Actually, the Many-Faced God is believed by the Faceless Men to be the only god. All the gods are just how different people choose to represent him. He has many faces, but he is one. Thus, the Faceless Men argue that nobody is wrong about which god is true, all of them are right, because all the gods are faces of the Many-Faced God.

Comment: That may be, but my point was that they equate the MFG with for example the Stranger. I don't think they'd equate him with the Father. Whether they'd say the Father doesn't exist or that he is misdescribed by those who follow the Seven I don't know.

Comment: I believe that they said at one point that all the Seven are simply different faces of MFG, and even the Seven are just one.

Comment: You could be right, I really don't remember. It's not really relevant to the question though ;)

Comment: Even worshipers of the Seven believe that the Seven are just different aspect of a single deity, much like the trinity is viewed by Catholics.

Comment: Not that I know of. It's very difficult to surmise anything about the ancient history of Planetos, as many of the narrators have limited knowledge themselves, poor records keeping in-universe as well as a (deliberate) lack of information from GRRM.

Comment: @Mooz Since I asked the TWOIAF was published. I have a copy but haven't finished reading it thoroughly. I wonder if it does drop some hints about this.

Comment: @curiousdannii I haven't read it yet, but I'd say probably not. Seems to me that GRRM is gearing up to reveal that there are no actual Gods, only some magic. Hence making it that they [the gods] are all the same in that none of them exist and the 'magic' acts get attributed to some newly made-up god based on the witness and the region etc. For example; in the Iron Islands they believe in the Drowned God, given that they are sea-faring people; in Lhazar they believe in the [Great Shepherd](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Great_Shepherd) because, well, they are goat herders, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is "no". Though I think it's a common thought for readers, I don't recall anyone in the main series explicitly saying any of the wind or sky gods are differing names for the same entity. I have also not seen any explicit indications of this in A World of Ice and Fire (though I have by no means read it cover-to-cover).

Comment: I don't understand most of your answer, could you [edit] it to make it more coherent?